# How do i install php 8 without php-fpm and nginx modules?

Tags: php, php-fpm, centos8

I am trying to install Apache2 + PHP 8.1 in a fresh install of a Centos 8.5 server.

This is my server setup:

```
[centos@api-stg html]$ cat /etc/*elease
CentOS Stream release 8
NAME="CentOS Stream"
VERSION="8"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Stream 8"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="CentOS Stream"
CentOS Stream release 8
CentOS Stream release 8
```

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-8-on-centos/), but when I got to the `sudo dnf install php php-mysqlnd` command I got the following to be installed:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:37:22 ago on Tue 08 Mar 2022 09:47:48 AM -05.
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Architecture                 Version                                                          Repository                          Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php                                    x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       1.7 M
 php-cli                                x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       5.3 M
 php-common                             x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       1.2 M
Installing dependencies:
 libsodium                              x86_64                       1.0.18-2.el8                                                     epel                               162 k
 oniguruma5php                          x86_64                       6.9.7.1-1.el8.remi                                               remi-safe                          210 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 nginx-filesystem                       noarch                       1:1.14.1-9.module_el8.0.0+1060+3ab382d3                          appstream                           24 k
 php-fpm                                x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       1.8 M
 php-mbstring                           x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       520 k
 php-opcache                            x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       627 k
 php-pdo                                x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       161 k
 php-sodium                             x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       101 k
 php-xml                                x86_64                       8.1.3-1.el8.remi                                                 remi-modular                       251 k
Enabling module streams:
 nginx                                                               1.14

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Install  12 Packages
```

Now, I don't want anything related to Nginx or php-fpm, is there a way to exclude those from my setup?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I don't want anything related to Nginx or php-fpm, is there a way to exclude those from my setup?

On CentOS >= 8, to enable PHP you NEED php-fpm. httpd is configured to use FastCGI (provided by php-fpm) using mod_proxy.

In above transaction, nginx is NOT installed (only nginx-filesystem which only owns a few directories for configuration files).

Installing httpd and php-fpm, and starting the services, and everything will work as expected.

P.S. It is still possible to use mod_php on C8 (so without php-fpm), but this is not recommended, and imply to switch httpd to prefork mode (which is bad for performance and security). It is not possible anymore on C9.

Comment: I did the install with fpm and now the server won't load PHP. I am getting a 503 error that doesn't explain much. `"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: check the log... /var/log/httpd and /var/log/php-fpm

Comment: as start with a simple test page:   `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`